# No Activity found to handle Intent android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE on Nokia 6.2 Android 9

Tags: android, android-intent

it works perfectly on other phones, the problem is only with Nokia

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_REQUEST_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
```

Answer (score 2):

it shows because your device hase no application for reading documents 
put code as below for checking it

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
      try {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        return;
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Log.w(TAG, "couldn't complete ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, no activity found. falling back.");
      }
```

you can check more clearly by [link2](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/commit/6e3751a0c5870f8dc4ad9d210ce08b153c3307bf)

Comment: or you can install any application for reading documents in your device

Comment: This is incorrect! This answer is for completely different intent Type! Question is about OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, not ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Answer (score 0):

Check if at least one activity exists to handle that `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_REQUEST_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Different type of **Chooser** to select document type. It is easy to use in android check Below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
String[] mimetypes = {"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "application/msword"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN);
```